# VueJS - Apply styles to slots wrapping elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, css-modules, vuejs-slots

I want to create a `Card` component using vue that has a header and content section using the [vuejs slots api](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

I am having trouble understanding how I can create a structure in my Card component. The card should contain all the wireframe styles (padding & margin), but be open for extension from the child template that uses the component.

I would like to know if there are any standard ways of styling wrapper elements with slots inside them from the child component.

The basic `Card` element has 2 slots wrapped with structural elements that I would like to allow the child template to modify where necessary.

```
<div class="Card">
  <header class="CardHeader">
    <slot name="header"></slot>
  </header>
  <div class="CardContent">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally I would like to add a `:class` attribute to the `#slot` element and have that be used on the element in the slot, however, it seems that the old syntax has been depreciated in the newest version of the framework eg.

```
<Card>
  <template #header class="extendHeader">
    stuff
  </template>
</Card>
```

I can think of 3 ways to do it that **will** work, each with their drawbacks.

1. Use props to add a class via the root element
2. Use a class on the root element and have style hooks on the components elements
3. Wrap the slot content in another element

A must for my project is using css-modules to reduce as much global css as possible because it has caused me so much grief in the past.

#### 1. Use props to add a class via the root element

This method would allow me to use css-modules and would make the `Card` elements open for extension

The component template would need to compose extra styles from the child template

```
<header :class="$style.Header, ...headerClasses]">
  <slot name="header"></slot>
</header>
```

The child template can then use `:header-classes` to extend the base Card classes, or overwrite unwanted styles.

```
<Card :header-classes="[$style.header]">
  <template #header>
    stuff
  </template>
</Card>
<style module>
  .header {
    background: var(--v-blue);
  }
</style>
```

#### 2. Use a class on the root element and have style hooks on the components elements

The `Card` template would need to assign extra classes that could be used to extend the base structural components of the component. The css-module classes should not be used as the names are hashed to avoid collisions.

```
<div :class="[$style.Card, 'CardStyleHook']">
  <header :class="[$style.Header, 'CardHeaderStyleHook']">
    <slot name="header"></slot>
  </header>
  <div :class="[$style.Content, 'CardContentStyleHook']">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then a single class could be added to the component and styles to the extra classes could be used

```
<Card :class="$style.extendCard">
  <template #header>
    stuff
  </template>
</Card>
<style module>
  .extendCard .CardHeaderStyleHook {
    background: var(--v-blue);
  }
</style>
```

#### 3. Wrap the slot content in another element

I think this kind of defeats the purpose of slots, and it will lead to issues where I need to remove the padding from the wrapping structural element in the `Card`, it's not really open for extension and would require more workarounds to allow this style to work.

```
<Card>
  <template #header>
    <div :class="$style.customHeader">
      stuff
    </div>
  </template>
</Card>
<style module>
  .customHeader{
    background: var(--v-blue);
  }
</style>
```

Is there any standard way to handle these cases since the old slots have been depreciated? have I missed something in the documentation, I have only been playing with vue for a couple of days so it's definitely possible.

There is full examples in the snippet below with working code if you need to provide any examples.

Thanks for any help!

```js
const use$styleMocking = {
  beforeMount() {
    // mock css-modules output
    this.$style = {
      Card: 'Card__x1337',
      Header: 'CardHeader__x1337',
      Content: 'CardContent__x1337',
    }
  }
}

Vue.component('Card', {
  template: '#card-template',
  mixins: [ use$styleMocking ],
  props: {
    cardClasses: { default: () => [] },
    headerClasses: { default: () => [] },
    contentClasses: { default: () => [] },
  }
})

Vue.component('style-hooked-card', {
  template: '#style-hooked-card-template',
  mixins: [ use$styleMocking ]
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#app-template'
})
```

```css
:root {
  --white: #fff;
  --v-teal: #00c58e;
  --v-jade: #108775;
  --v-blue: #2f495e;
  --card-padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  --grid-gap: 1.25rem;
}

html, body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.44;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: var(--grid-gap);
  grid-row-gap: var(--grid-gap);
}

/* --------- Card Styles --------- */
/*
  styles have __x1337 to mock css-modules, the client should never know the hash
  and should not use it to style elements
*/
.Card__x1337 {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  transition: 400ms box-shadow;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1;
}
.CardHeader__x1337 {
  padding: var(--card-padding);
  background: var(--v-teal);
}
.CardHeader__x1337 h3 {
  color: var(--v-blue);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.CardContent__x1337 {
  padding: var(--card-padding);
}
/* --------- End Card Styles --------- */

.extendHeader {
  background: var(--v-blue);
}

.extendHeader h3 {
  color: var(--white);
}

.extendCard .CardHeaderStyleHook {
  background: var(--v-jade);
}

.extendCard .CardHeaderStyleHook h3 {
  color: var(--white);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<template type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <main class="main">
    <Card>
      <template #header class="extendHeader">
        <h3>Basic Card Styles</h3>
      </template>
      <template>
        <p>It would be ideal to add a class to the template and have it available to add to the classes of the wrapper element around slots</p>
      </template>
    </Card>
    
    <Card :header-classes="['extendHeader']">
      <template #header>
        <h3>1. Extend Header Styles</h3>
      </template>
      <template>
        <p>This card uses props on the Card to extend the wrapper class, this example is using a global class, but this would use css-modules locally scoped classes correctly</p>
      </template>
    </Card>
    
    <Style-Hooked-Card class="extendCard">
      <template #header>
        <h3>2. Extend Card Styles</h3>
      </template>
      <template>
        <p>This card adds a hook class to every component so that it can be extended from the outside</p>
      </template>
    </Style-Hooked-Card>
  </main>
</template>

<template type="text/x-template" id="card-template">
  <div :class="[$style.Card, ...cardClasses]">
    <header :class="[$style.Header, ...headerClasses]">
      <slot name="header"></slot>
    </header>
    <div :class="[$style.Content, ...contentClasses]">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template type="text/x-template" id="style-hooked-card-template">
  <div :class="[$style.Card, 'CardStyleHook']">
    <header :class="[$style.Header, 'CardHeaderStyleHook']">
      <slot name="header"></slot>
    </header>
    <div :class="[$style.Content, 'CardContentStyleHook']">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app"></div>
```